# Comparing and highlighting phrases in text with php

Tags: php

I have an array of words `$duplicate_words` and a string `$contents`. I want to search for the words in the string and highlight them when there is a match.

I can highlight single duplicate words, but I don't want to highlight single words - I want to highlight only when two or more words match there. I've been trying to find a solution for over a week without success. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to find and highlight the string in your IDE, or you want to create a program that can do that?

Comment: i want to make a program for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$no_of_matches = preg_match_all('/'.$duplicate_word.'/', $string, $matches);

if($no_of_matches > 1){
    $string = str_replace($duplicate_word, '<span class="highlight">' . $duplicate_word . '</span>', $string);
}
```